# How can I use awesomebox.sty in Debian stretch/buster with pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, texlive, debian

I have a latex document which uses the `awesomebox` package. 
On my old Widows system with MikTeX I could easyly install this package and use it with `pdflatex`.

Now im using Linux and want to install it too. I installed texlive via the debian repository.

A bit of searching located the `awesomebox` package in the `texlive-xetex` debian-package and I installed it.

But if I compile my document with `pdflatex` I get the following error:

```
 ! Package awesomebox Error: You are trying to use awesomebox
(awesomebox)                 with something else than xelatex or luatex .

See the awesomebox package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
```

What can I do to use the package with `pdflatex`? 
The use of windows or not pdlatex is not an option!

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{awesomebox}
\begin{document}

\warningbox{Warn me of something}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me using pdflatex on Ubuntu with the packaged texlive installation.   Just do `sudo apt install texlive-full` on the command line and it should work.  Not sure why it isn't working for you.  Perhaps the fact that you got it from the texlive-xetex package is what's doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you quoted should happen when using old versions of `awesomebox.sty` with a TeX engine different from XeTeX and LuaTeX. This is indeed the case with the version of `awesomebox` in Debian `stretch`, but not with the version from Debian `buster`.

Start of `awesomebox.sty` in Debian `stretch`:

```latex
\RequirePackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\newif\ifawesomebox@notxetex\awesomebox@notxetextrue
\ifxetex
  \awesomebox@notxetexfalse
\else
  \ifluatex
    \awesomebox@notxetexfalse
  \fi
\fi

\ifawesomebox@notxetex
\PackageError{awesomebox}{%
  You are trying to use awesomebox\MessageBreak
  with something else than xelatex or luatex
}{%
  Please abort now with <ctrl+d>
}
\fi
```

Start of `awesomebox.sty` in Debian `buster`:

```latex
% Try to just depend on fontawesome5 package
% https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5
\RequirePackage{fontawesome5}
```

If you look at the [upstream website](https://git.deparis.io/latex-awesomebox/about/), it seems that using `fontawesome5` as opposed to `fontawesome`, is what allowed `awesomebox.sty` not to be limited to XeTeX and LuaTeX anymore. This can be somehow confirmed by comparing `/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/awesomebox/README` in `stretch`:

> (...) This means all the magic of this package only exists if you previously
>   installed FontAwesome on your system and made it available for use with
>   XeTeX. Yes, this package requires you to use XeLaTeX too.

with `/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/awesomebox/README.md` in `buster`:

> Awesome Boxes is all about drawing admonition blocks around text to
>   inform or alert your readers about something particular. The specific
>   aim of this package is to use [FontAwesome 5](https://fontawesome.com)
>   icons to ease the illustration of these blocks. (...)

(no mention of the TeX engine requirement anymore).

Conclusion: either you didn't try it in `buster`, or you have an old version of `awesomebox.sty` that shadows the one from `buster`. In the latter case:

1. First run `mktexlsr` as root.
2. Then, under your normal user account for LaTeX, run `kpsewhich awesomebox.sty` to identify the precise file LaTeX is using (you may also want to try `kpsewhere awesomebox.sty` to list *all* files with this name found in the various TEXMF trees).